# Issues with twig embed and extend

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to extend block embedded or included in child template

I want to extend blocks top,bottom,left and right in page templates which extend layout.html.twig

Code for vertical_boxes.html.twig:

```
<div class="top_box">
    {% block top %}
        Top box default content
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div class="bottom_box">
    {% block bottom %}
        Bottom box default content
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Code for horizontal_boxes.html.twig:

```
<div class="left_box">
    {% block left %}
        Left box default content
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div class="right_box">
    {% block right %}
        Right box default content
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Code for layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    {% embed page_type ~ "_boxes.html.twig" %}

    {% endembed %}

{% endblock %}
```

Page1 template page1.twig:

```
{% extends("::layout.html.twig") %}

{% set page_type= 'vertical' %}

{% block top %}
     Page1 content
{% endblock %}

{% block bottom %}
     Page1 content
{% endblock %}
```

Page2 template page2.twig:

```
{% extends("::layout.html.twig") %}

{% set page_type= 'horizontal' %}

{% block left %}
     Page2 content
{% endblock %}

{% block right%}
     Page2 content
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna work. What I would do is creating a block in layout that should contain boxes and then embed the boxes in page1.twig and page2.twig.

The embed tag works exactly like include with added benefit of allow extending the blocks defined in the embedded template. What you get after embedding doesn't contain blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First you should capture all blocks defined in children into variables.

Then pass them to embedded blocks.

```
{# parent.html.twig #}

{% set left_block %}{% block left %}{% endblock %}{% endset %}
{% set right_block %}{% block right %}{% endblock %}{% endset %}
{% set top_block %}{% block top %}{% endblock %}{% endset %}
{% set bottom_block %}{% block bottom %}{% endblock %}{% endset %}

{% embed page_type ~ "_boxes.html.twig" %}
    {% block left %}{{ left_block }}{% endblock %}
    {% block right %}{{ right_block }}{% endblock %}
    {% block top %}{{ top_block }}{% endblock %}
    {% block bottom %}{{ bottom_block }}{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Blocks such as [left, right|top, bottom] are odd for [vertical|horizontal]_boxes, however they're simply ignored as boxes does not have these blocks.

Hope it works & helps.